# Where to find more info about a Foundation method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to better understand some memory management concepts. In order to do so, I need to see the implementation of `NSDateFormatter:stringFromDate` method. Developer documentation refers to `NSDateFormatter.h`, where the method is declared. Following a logical reasoning, I looked for the implementation in it's theoretical counterpart, `NSDateFormatter.m`, but I was unable to find that in Finder.

Where can I see that method's implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The Foundation and UIKit frameworks are not open source. The headers are there so that you can build against the Cocoa libraries, but the implementations are intentionally opaque.

---

That said, some of the Carbon stuff underlying Foundation on the Mac side is open source, so if you go digging, you might get some idea of how some things work, e.g.
http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.29/CFDateFormatter.c
But this is unlikely to help you if you're just trying to learn about some memory management concepts. In that case, you're better off just asking those questions here on SO about the classes you're interested in.

Comment: Understand. So the question is: how can I know whether the convenience method `NSDateFormatter:stringFromDate` allocates the object it creates with `autorelease` or not?

Comment: If you don't call `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `retain`, then you aren't responsible for releasing it.  This is a fundamental rule for Cocoa.  See [the Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

As quixoto said, the frameworks you are looking for are closed-source.  However [the GNUstep open-source project](http://www.gnustep.org/) aims to reimplement Cocoa, and they have [an implementation of NSDateFormatter](http://svn.gna.org/viewcvs/gnustep/libs/base/trunk/Source/NSDateFormatter.m?view=markup) that you can see.  If you are looking to read a lot of internal framework source code, that's one place to start.